# iOS play video as downloaded data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am downloading a video from remote server. while download in progress what ever data downloaded in current(not full download), I want to play that data in a video player. if the file size is 10 MB, when I start download if 0.5 Mb downloaded I want to play that 0.5MB video, while downloading It has to play. I dont' want to stream, because next time I can play it from local file.
is there any video player available in iOS?.

Comment: On server-side use streaming e.g. Wowza https://www.wowza.com/ etc. By using streaming URL you can play video without downloading it completely

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you are asking for is called a progressive download, which is performed over HTTP protocol (RTSP is for streaming) and HTTP server is required (instead of Streaming server).

You can play the progressive download streaming from a simple java server https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/StreamX

iOS devices support HTTP progressive download for .mp4 files..